# How to start and gracefully stop dotnet-counters collect process remotely?

Tags: .net, dotnet-counters

I have several remote VMs that I need to be able to run a dotnet-counters collect process on in order to capture and export event counters to a csv file. I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is. I was thinking of copying a shell script that executes the dotnet-counters command, but then I have no idea how to stop the process gracefully. When running dotnet-counters manually it waits for you to hit the Q key to stop collecting. How would I do that via scripting though? Or is there a better way of doing it?